# How to get latest file using "urllib2" by reading html directory in python

Tags: python, html, http, python-2.7, urllib2

I would like to read latest file from http folder

'releases' folder should be like 0001.tgz, 0002.tgz, 0003.tgz
how to make 0003 will be select?

```
import urllib2

url = "http://example.com/releases"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
...
```

Thanks. Give me some example.

Comment: Do you have access to a directory index for that directory?

Comment: yes, it was HTML format. sort by latest or do a mapping for date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to parse the directory index and find the latest file, which is *presumably* last in the index, based on your naming convention.

Something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://example.com/releases"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

last_link = soup.find_all('a', href=True)[-1]

latest_content = urllib2.urlopen(last_link['href']).read()
# do stuff
```

If that won't work, grab all of the links using `find_all` and do some more careful parsing based on the filenames.

Comment: Yes, this what I'm looking for. Mapping "href" and get the last one. Thank for the good example.

Comment: This assumes that there are no other file types in the directory.

Comment: Yes, it does. But he can still use `find_all` and filter by file extension, in the case that there _are_ more than one file type (which it doesn't sound like there are).

Answer (score 0):

If the .tgz files are sequential, then count down from the maximum and stop the loop when you get to the first (newest) file.

```
import urllib2

for counter in xrange(9999,0,-1):
    fyle = str(counter).zfill(4) # pad zeros
    url = "http://example.com/releases/"+fyle+".tgz"
    ret = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    if ret.code == 200:
        print "Exists:",fyle
        break

    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Comment: This code also can be use. This is very helpful. Thank you very much for this example.

Comment: You're welcome! I'd be curious about speed for your specific application.